# IS-A and HAS-A relationship occur together in OOPS

Tags: java, oop

In Java every class is a child of Object. So a class IS-A Object. Now if it contains a data member of Object type (actually any type in this case), then it would be HAS-A relationship.
Related to above statement I have following doubts.
1. Is there a name for this relationship, IS-A and HAS-A coming together?
2. Are there any real world example for it?
3. From OOPS perspective, is it okay to have this relationship or should be avoided?

Comment: I'd like to see how you avoid having a class that extends `Object`.

Comment: you can't avoid extending Object class to your class. There is no way.

Comment: You are probably over-thinking these concepts, because any meaningful class has attributes of some sorts (and also is an Object).

Comment: I dont think it would be correct to say "a class IS-A Object". A class is nothing but a blueprint or a template for creating different objects which __defines its properties and behaviors__ .

Comment: A dog IS-A animal. A dog HAS-A bark. A cat IS-A animal. A cat HAS-A meow. IS-A simply implies that you are extending whatever the object at hand is. Where HAS-A means your object HAS instances of an object

Comment: This is such a typical relation pattern that I don's know a special name for it. A real world example: a MAN is a HUMAN-BEING and has a HUMAN-BEING as his father and possibly some HUMAN-BEINGs as children. (By the way, from this example, you see that it's important to name the role of HAS-A relations (father, child, ...), otherwise they're just meaningless).

Comment: @Mick maybe. But today while implementing another use case, I ended up with similar scenario. At that time I wasn't sure if it's the right way to do hence posted this question.

Comment: @Tommy Object is a class in Java.

Comment: @driteknight I never said that it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is there a name for this relationship, IS-A and HAS-A coming together?

No.

> 2. Are there any real world example for it?

```
List<Set> aListThatContainsSets
```

List and Set are both Collections.  In this example a List has a bunch of Sets.

> 3. From OOPS perspective, is it okay to have this relationship or should be avoided?

Yes its fine.  You can even HAS-A yourself.

```
public class MyClass{

     MyClass me;

}
```