# OOPS composition and IS-A relationship

Tags: python, oop

I tried searching on this topic but could not find anything then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182966/is-a-and-has-a-relationship-occur-together-in-oops).
I have created a class where there is a need of OwnsA and ISA relationship. I am no expert or mature dev at oops *so need to know* if below code falls within practices of oops.
Basically, a traveller can go with default plan provided by agency or can create his own plan

```
class Plan():

        def __init__(self,m):
            self.m = m


class Traveller():

    def __init__(self, _name):
        self.name = _name

    class Create_Own_Plan(Plan):

        def __init__(self, _id):
            self.id = _id
```

Comment: Beside **not** initalizing inherited `class Plan` using `super().__init__(m=?)` it looks OK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Having verbs in class names is suspicious. Verbs are usually associated with actions and these with class methods, not class names that are used to create objects. Also in Python you can use `self.name = name` without problem. But `id` is a built-in function. Use `id_` instead. Reserve `_` prefixes to signal your intention that some variable should be for private use in the class (there are really no private names in Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Traveller` has a `Plan`. A `Plan` created by the Agency or a custom plan, are both just a `Plan` object you create and then assign to the `Traveller`, upon creation or later. You don't need a `CustomPlan`, because probably only the `Plan` attribute values are different from `Plan` to `Plan`. You just create new different Plans:

So

```
agency_plan = Plan(some_data)
custom_plan = Plan(some_other_data)
```

If you have really different Plans (on data member attributes or behaviours) you can have

```
class CustomPlan1(Plan):
    ...
```

with the advantage that it is still Plan and can be used as such.

```
class Plan():
    def __init__(self, plan_data):
        self.setupPlan(plan_data)

    def setupPlan(self, data):
        ...
        # configure the plan attributes based on data
        ...

class Traveller():
    def __init__(self, name, plan=None):
        self.name = name
        if plan:
            self.plan = plan

traveller1 = Traveller('John', agency_plan)
traveller2 = Traveller('Mary', custom_plan)
traveller3 = Traveller('Alice')
...
custom_plan2 = Plan(some_other_data2)
traveller3.plan = custom_plan2
```

Comment: My worry is -  **Plan** is something that is owned by Agency. A traveller registering with Agency would **HAS-A** plan given by agency. However, when traveller designs their own plan i want it to be Traveller **OWNS-A** plan i.e. custom plan should get destroyed when Traveller object finishes. Though i am going hard with verbs, which i could be wrong, i plan to rectify this.

Comment: @Avij You can give Traveller a reference to an Agency plan. Like I did I am passing references. You can also change the code, in case of a custom plan, to create that custom_plan object inside the Travellers init and assign it to self.plan. That will go way with the Travellers object.

Comment: For an object to be destroyed you have to make sure there are no more references to it. This is related but a bit different from your OOP "destroy with" thinking. It has to do with objects scope and reference counting. If there are more references to an owned object from outside the class you may have to `del` those names to really destroy the plan.

Comment: If i understood you right, To implement OWNS-A relation i need to create Custom plan object from somewhere inside the Traveller class methods and that ways this object goes away when a traveller object finished and for Agency plans i can just have Agency's Plan object(created outside from traveller) as reference, thus this Agency's Plan can remain alive even if traveller object finishes.

Comment: Yes, object would be in memory if there are references to it, even del would not work in that case, would it?

Comment: That's right you can for example have a list named `agency_plans` with all the plans outside the class. For the Traveller's owned ones it is not sufficient to be created inside a method, it has to be assigned to some instance attribute like self.plan. Otherwise it goes out of scope at methods' end.

Comment: del only deletes the name (the reference) not the object. It it's the last reference the object will be garbage collected (and this is guaranteed but can happen later, not necessarily at del moment)